# Gershgorin interval of an eigenvalue and the largest coordinate of the corresponding eigenvector

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A=(a_{ij})$ be an $n\times n$ symmetric matrix with positive diagonal entries.
The smallest eigenvalue, $\lambda_1$, is simple, and the  corresponding  unit eigenvector has all coordinates, $x_i>0$. I know that
$\lambda_1\in (a_{ss}-r_s, a_{ss})$, where $a_{ss}=\min\{a_{ii}, i=\overline{1,n}\}$, and $r_s=\sum_{j\neq s}|a_{sj}|$.

In order to deduce the Gershgorin interval containing an eigenvalue one uses the largest value among the absolute values of the coordinates of a corresponding eigenvector: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gershgorin_circle_theorem.
My question is whether  in my case, the a priori knowledge of the location of the smallest eigenvalue  necessarily implies that $\max\{|x_i|, i=\overline{1,n}\}=x_s$.