# Gershgorin Circle Theorem: counterexample to a statement in the proof?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, gershgorin-sets

I have been struggling to comprehend the proof of [Gershgorin Circle Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gershgorin_circle_theorem) for a long time now, but I think I have come upon a counterexample. I'm probably wrong, but please tell me where I'm wrong...

Theorem: Every eigenvalue of A lies within at least one of the Gershgorin discs $D(a_{ii},R_i)$.

**Proof:** $$Av=\lambda v \implies \sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij}x_j = \lambda x_i \ \ \forall \ \ i \in \{1,2,...,n\}$$ where $|x_i|=\max_{j} {x_j}$ for $x_j$ elements of the eigenvector.

And so on.

**But what if** $$A=\left(\begin{matrix} 1 & 0 \\ 1 & -1 \end{matrix}\right), \ \ \lambda_1 = -1, \lambda_2=1 \ \ , v_1=(0,1)^T?$$ Then $x_1=0$ always, $x_2$ is free. Then $x_i = 1$, and $a_{11}+a_{12}=0 \neq (-1)(1) = 1$.

What am I missing?

Comment: For your matrix $A$, the theorem tells you that one eigenvalue lies in $D(1,0)$ and one in $D(-1,1)$. What's the contradiction?

Comment: @TMN The contradiction, the OP claims, is not with the GCT but with a statement used in the proof of the theorem.

Comment: @GitGud My question echoes the exact same as this question. If you could answer this it would be great. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/394203/gershgorin-interval-of-an-eigenvalue-and-the-largest-coordinate-of-the-correspon?rq=1

Comment: @Anonymous I don't really understand the other question. If you wish to follow wikipedia's proof of the theorem, I can help you with it.

Comment: @GitGud OK. Can we chat?

Comment: @Anonymous Sure.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13634/discussion-between-anonymous-and-git-gud)

Comment: @ GregMartin Useful edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that I was getting confused by the last line in this paragraph, in this proof on Wikipedia:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gershgorin_circle_theorem

Proof: Let $λ$ be an eigenvalue of A and let $x = (x_j)$ be a corresponding eigenvector. Let $i∈{1,…,n}$ be chosen so that $|x_i| = \max_j |x_j|$. (That is to say, choose $i$ so that $x_i$ is the largest (in absolute value) number in the vector $x$). Then $|x_i| > 0$, otherwise $x = 0$. Since $x$ is an eigenvector, $Ax = λx$, and thus: $\sum \limits_j a_{ij} x_j = \lambda x_i \quad \forall i \in \{1, \ldots, n\}$.

Since $i$ is a bounded variable, it is ok to write it the way it as has been written and it can rewritten as $\sum \limits_j a_{kj} x_j = \lambda x_k \quad \forall k \in \{1, \ldots, n\}$. On the following line what they do is particularize that universal statement to $k=i$ (remember $i$ was already fixed). Therefore, everything falls in place.